# Expand Street Network passing through points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, network, traffic, attribute-joins

I have a road network (red) passing through some traffic data points (green):
[image]

I want to expand this network to include all of the points. I already have a bigger street network (blue) from which I can take the missing streets.

[image]

I am using QGIS.

It would be great if the traffic data of the points could be associated to the street passing through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your traffic points are intersecting the road network, you can use the **Join attributes by location** tool from the toolbar:

*Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location...*

I use the following options to make sure I get all the attributes from both layers and delete the ones I no longer need. This should provide you with a point layer which contains the original traffic attributes and the attributes of the road network (i.e. which street the point is on).

[image: Join attributes by location interface]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
So I discovered that when I zoom on the layer, most of the points don't actually intersect the street network. So I created a 10m buffer around the steet network (the final aim is to keep only the streets that intersect the traffic points). This should be fine as now I see that the street network intersect most of the points.

Comment: However, when I try to use the Join attributes by location tool with "Keep all records", it creates a new street network exactly the same as the one I had before (it keeps even the streets that don't instersect a traffic point). If I don't choose this option, I get an empty layer. 
The two layers are in different projections (that's the only way I managed to have them in the same position on the map).

Comment: @FraTanti - The tool (like most tools) will only really work if both layers are in the same CRS. Did you use the `Save As...` option on the layers and save them in the same CRS? I find it quite strange why two related layers should be in different projections...=)

Comment: OK, I managed to project them in the same CRS and it worked. In Attribute Summary I select:
Take summary of the intersecting figures --> Sum
However, it only calculated the sum of some of the columns (not the ones I needed). Is there a way to decide of which columns perform the sum?

Comment: @FraTanti - Not with this tool but I think you can with the **Spatial Join** tool from the **MMQGIS** plugin, you may need to install/enable this from the toolbar: _Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins..._. The plugin should be shown as a separate menu in the toolbar (_MMQGIS > Combine > Spatial Join_) and allows you to choose which fields you want to keep in the output.